# visualize data in bar chart using python

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my data inside my PostgreSQL. I need to create a bar chart (y-axis: number of post, x-axis: student_id). so I run SQL Script in Python and visualise using python.

[image]

here is my code:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

con = psycopg2.connect(
            host = "",
            database="",
            port="",
            user = "",
            password = "")

cur = con.cursor()

query= 'select student_id, count(student_id) as numberpost from forum group by student_id'

df=pd.read_sql(query,con)

plt.bar(x=df['student_id'],
        height=df['numberpost'])
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

However, I didn't get the output as I want. This is the output that I get.

[image]

It should be student_id data in the x-axis, and numberpost data in the y-axis.

[image]

Anyone can help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: The problem seems to be the large range of student_id values, as it's read as integers. Maybe try passing them as strings instead? So `plt.bar(x=df['student_id'].to_string(), ...`

Comment: @Energya, I did that, but the output I got as below:
<img src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yYFqoUUehj2aqTJZKvEt-g2qmQ6-heTG/view?usp=sharing">

Comment: Then you need to adjust your `xticks` accordingly, try searching for that

Comment: alright, thank you :-)

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be the large range of `student_id` values, as it's read as integers.

Maybe try passing them as strings instead? So try

```
plt.bar(x=df['student_id'].to_string(), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with the code below and it worked fine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['student_id'] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
df['numberpost'] = [12,3,4,3,4,5,334]

plt.bar(x=df['student_id'],
        height=df['numberpost'])
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)
plt.show()
```

My guess is your dataframe does not contain data.

Have you checked to see if the `df` contains data?

I assume your `con` variable actually defines parameters (or you left them out for anonymity) as well?

Simply testing with `df.head()` will tell you if you have results.

Comment: I tested using df.head(), I have data in my dataframe. about the con, yes I left them out for anonymity, This is the output when I tested using df.head()

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ifg2R7-pmU_TVO6s6y4gebAYK9gcnisT/view?usp=sharing